# use 2 Regular expressions in single text box in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I create a single text box.And validating a following e-mail id's using a Regular expressions

ex

```
    hai@gmail.com

    hai@gmail.co.in
```

my text box allow both e-mail types.

using client side in asp.net

Comment: That's great, there but isn't a question.

Comment: So you want a regex which accepts both emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex with a [`RegularExpressionValidator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahwtc9e(v=vs.100).aspx):

`\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*`

Tested with:

```
var emailRegex = new Regex(@"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

bool isValidEmail = emailRegex.IsMatch("hai@gmail.com"); // true
isValidEmail = emailRegex.IsMatch("hai@gmail.co.in"); // true
```